# Update DIV with content from an AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hello my question is this: I have **two divs**, one div contain @ajax.beginform, and the other div is empty but hidden. The idea I have is that the div with the form in, to make ajax request, the action method of the controller detects whether the model is valid, **if not valid**, re-send the same content of the form (one partialview with contents of the form) but with validation errors; **if the model is valid**, it returns another partialview content with a simple "thank you" and displayed in the div is hidden, then it should hide the div that has the form . I do not know how I can do this??? My idea is that the onSuccess event of @ajax.beginform has as parameter, the html returned by the server, but do not know what content returning the server, ie, i do not know what div display. Help me please.

PD:if the question is not understood, let me know and I'll give an example.

[[[[[[UPDATE]]]]]]

I Have a **model**:

`public class Message{`

```
    public int MessageID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string From { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

I have a **controller**:

`public class MessageController : Controller{`

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult saveMessage(Message msg) {
        // (ModelState.IsValid)
        if (!msg.From.Contains("@")) {

            ModelState.AddModelError("From", "The mail must contain an @");
            return PartialView("DataMsg", msg);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("thanks");
    }

    public PartialViewResult thanks() {
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

and my views:

**Index.cshtml**:

`@model MvcApplication1.Models.Message`

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@section scripts{
    <script>
        function successMsg(data) {
        // I want the "thank you" is displayed in the div with id="thanksUpdate" and not in #formUpdate
           $("#formUpdate").html(data);
        }
    </script>
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("saveMessage", 
    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod="Post", OnSuccess="successMsg"})) {
    <div id="formUpdate">
        @Html.Partial("DataMsg", Model);
    </div>
}


<div id="thanksUpdate" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

**DataMsg.cshtml**:

`@model MvcApplication1.Models.Message`

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.From)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.From)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.From)

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Content)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Content)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Content)

<input type="submit" value="Send" />
```

and **thanks.cshtml**:

`<h2>Thank you</h2>`

I want the "thank you" is displayed in the div with id="thanksUpdate" and not in #formUpdate. How I can do that???

Comment: Sending data to the server and the server handling the data it receives are 2 entirely different subjects. If you have any code, you should post it.

Comment: Hi Jon, I will add the necessary code

Answer (score 0):

well I found a way to fix was to send a cookie in the response from my controller, and the client side see the value sent, if the value is 501, redisplays the same div, else, it is shown in the other div. I do not know if it is a good solution. Please any answer will help.

In the **Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult saveMessage(Message msg) {                                                      

    if (!msg.From.Contains("@")) {
        ModelState.AddModelError("From", "The mail must contain an @");
        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("resultado", "501"));
        return PartialView("DataMsg", msg);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("thanks");
}  

public PartialViewResult thanks() {

    Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("resultado", "502"));
    return PartialView();
}
```

In **view** Index.cshtml:

`@section scripts{`

```
<script>
    function successMsg(data) {
        //alert(data);
        var c = $.cookie("resultado");

        if (c == '501') {
            $("#formUpdate").html(data);
        } else {
            $("#thanksUpdate").html(data).show();

            $("#formUpdate").hide();
        }
    }
</script>
}
```